# Switching between Fragments with button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my app, I have one activity and two fragments. What I'm trying to do, is to navigate between this two fragments back or front with button. Each navigate button is defined in fragment.

The first problem is, with the code that is below, I get the **exception** on application run:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MainActivity}: 
            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0050 for fragment Fragment1{b41da690 #0 id=0x7f0c0050}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0050 for fragment Fragment1{b41da690 #0 id=0x7f0c0050}
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:823)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**CODE:**

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set desired fragment for the first time
        setFragment(this, new Fragment1());
    }

    public void switch_fragment(View view, String fragmentID) {
        Fragment newFragment = null;
        switch (fragmentID) {
            case Fragment1.ID:
                newFragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case Fragment2.ID:
                newFragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
        }
        setFragment(this, newFragment);
    }

    public static void setFragment(Activity activity, Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeHolder, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

***main_activity.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        />
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

***Fragment1.java***

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public static final String ID = "1";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

}
```

***fragment1.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO TO FRAGMENT 1"
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:onClick="switch_fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

***Fragment2.java***

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public static final String ID = "2";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }

}
```

***fragment2.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO TO FRAGMENT 2"
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:onClick="switch_fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If this sample is wrong way of achieving this, can you please link some similar example for newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a very important part is `setContentView` and before using replace you should have an existing fragment. So in `onCreate` change:

```
// set desired fragment for the first time
        setFragment(this, new Fragment1());
```

Should be changed to:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);//then
   // set desired fragment for the first time
   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    // The id specified here identifies which ViewGroup to
    // append the Fragment to.
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_placeHolder, new Fragment1());
    ft.commit();
```

Try to replace:

```
... activity.getFragmentManager()
```

With:

```
... getSupportFragmentManager()
```

and remove:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    />
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    />
```

Finally, change the `switch_fragment` to:

```
public void switch_fragment(View view) {
        Fragment newFragment = null;
        switch (view.getID()) {
            case R.id.btn_2:
                newFragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_1:
                newFragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
        }
        setFragment(this, newFragment);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using API 16 so I can not call "getSupportFragmentManager()" :/ I have also removed fragment from main_activtiy.xml, but did not fix the problem

Comment: It is from `AppCompatActivity` of  `android.support.v7.app` and should be able to use with any targeting version

Comment: True, ok one moment, let me try

Comment: After changing the imports to android.support.v4.app., it is still throwing the same error

Comment: Ok, so I got your idea. In order to replace fragment we need first to have an existing one. So what happens now with new changes, is that I can run my app with activity and with `fragment1` which was created in the method `onCreate`. However, when I press the button to go to second fragment2, it throws exception again.

Comment: This exception occurs when I click on the button to switch to next Fragment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method switch_fragment(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn_2`

Comment: But this is different ID, from the View. Which i must set exlipcitly somehow in the fragment onCreateView. I guess I should just create listener for this buttons inside this fragments, i think that is better solution. Be right back.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of using static fragment ID. The solution can guarantee to switch fragment based on button ID. If you set 'onClick' in XML, you have to follow my code. Otherwise, remove onClick and write more code for fragment to handle button click :)

Comment: Correct! However, I got some new exception when i was creating the button and initializing it with `btn_id`in fragment `        `Button btn = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SuperUtil.setFragment(getActivity(), new FragmentZadatak2());
            }
        });`... This is throwing now Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException.. I got to go now, see you later.

Answer (score 0):

remove below code from your activity layout file,

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        />
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        />
```

Also please use below in your fragment before your return statement,

```
super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

and try to run your code.

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope that will work for you.

Comment: DId just like you said, but I'm still getting the exception.